# Split SQL column values and group by date and return single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server query , using this , I am splitting event id sum columns to two columns based on some condition. Query executed successfully, but the result is not desired. It's half useful. Please help me to get expected result. I want one row for both  split columns instead two rows and empty spaces.
SQL Query:

```
select convert(date, paymenttime)) , SUM(case when eventid = 33 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column1, 
SUM(case when eventid = 36 then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column2
from tbltransMain_backup where 
paymentime <= '20160731' and PaymentTime >= '20160701'
group by convert(date,paymenttime),event_id
order by convert(date,paymenttime)
```

Result view:
[image: SQL Result View]

Expected Result:

```
2016-07-01 27 1
2016-07-02 28 2
2016-07-03 30 15
```

Comment: please paste the expected result as text

Comment: Thanks TheGameiswar. My expected result was : 2016-07-01 27 1  , 2016-07-02 28 2 , One row for each date.

Comment: Your text query looks OK `group by convert(date,paymenttime)`, contrary to picture which is `group by convert(date,paymenttime), event_id`.

Comment: Thanks, Serg. I unknowingly wrote a correct query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you posted (perhaps unknowingly) into your question should already give you the desired results:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, paymenttime),
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_id = 33 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN event_id = 36 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column2
FROM tbltransMain_backup
WHERE paymentime <= '20160731' AND
      paymentime >= '20160701'
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, paymenttime)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, paymenttime)
```

The reason you were getting two rows for every date is that your query had the following grouping:

```
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, paymenttime),
         event_id
```

In other words, each date would have *two* groups, one for `event_id = 33` and one for `event_id = 36`.